# Two float divs beside one and float vs margin

Tags: css, html, layout, css-float

I want to create this layout`:`

```
------------------ -------
|   div header   | | div |
|________________| |     |
_________________  |  p  |
|                | |  a  |
|                | |  n  |
|  div content   | |  e  |
|                | |  l  |
|________________| |_____|
```

It's placed in container div. But problem is that panel div is aligned identically as content div.
There is my code:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 1184px; min-height: 1504px; border: thin dashed; margin: 0px auto;">
  <div id="header" style=" border: thin solid; float: left; margin-bottom: 20px; width: 930px; height: 150px;">
  </div>
  <div id="content" style="border: thin solid; float: left; width: 930px; min-height: 1330px;">
  </div>
  <div id="panel" style="border: thin solid; float: right; min-height: inherit; width: 230px; margin-left: 20px; height: inherit">
  </div>
</div>
```

I try search answer there but unsuccessfully. I try combination of float, clear and display params but without result. I get final layout only if I swap the order of divs and get panel div before content div but this change impossible me use inherit height in panel div. I need panel div height according to container (container div height is automatic by  content div and header div with margin).
Next, container height is automatic only if I set float param but margin param becomes inoperable. 
Can someone help me solve these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/ppollono/e9HJ3/1/)

the trick is using

```
display:table
```

and

```
display: table-cell
```

With this solution no matters the content in the #content the sidebar will have the correct height

Comment: Yeah, it seems to my expectations. I tried display table and table cell params but evidently not correctly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Edit: Can you help me with one more little thing? When I try get panel content into panel div content isn't from top border but it's displayed like element with applied margin-top param or with padding-top applied in panel div. It's also manifested in your link. Display param applied on panel div or inside element did't solve it.

Comment: no problem!!
Also learn about Flexbox display

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

http://caniuse.com/flexbox
It´s not supported by all browsers but soon!!

Answer (score 0):

Just re-order the divs so the panel comes before the content:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 1184px; min-height: 1504px; border: thin dashed; margin: 0px auto;">
    <div id="header" style=" border: thin solid; float: left; margin-bottom: 20px; width: 930px; height: 150px;"></div>
    <div id="panel" style="border: thin solid; float: right; min-height: inherit; width: 230px; margin-left: 20px; height: inherit"></div>
    <div id="content" style="border: thin solid; float: left; width: 930px; min-height: 1330px;"></div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/e9HJ3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping the two left divs in their own div:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 1184px; min-height: 1504px; border: thin dashed; margin: 0px auto;">
  <div id="wrapper" style="float: left; width: 930px;">
      <div id="header" style="border: thin solid; margin-bottom: 20px; width: 930px; height: 150px;"></div>
      <div id="content" style="border: thin solid; min-height: 1330px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="panel" style="border: thin solid; float: right; min-height: inherit; width: 230px; margin-left: 20px; height: inherit"></div>
</div>
```

I'd also recommend using `display: inline-block;` instead of `float`. The behaviour is slightly different, but, if I understand you correctly, this would solve the problems you're having with the automatic height of the container div.

Answer (score 0):

[**JSFiddle!**](http://jsfiddle.net/2WtM2/4/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftside">
        <div class="innertop">
        Blah! Blah!!
        </div>
        <div class="innermid">
        Blah! Blah!!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightvertical">
    </div>
</div>
```

You could first do the vertical divisions that you want inside the page as apparent in my JSfiddle example, once you have got a clearer understanding of the different vertical divisions, then you can place other divisions inside those, this way its more concrete, and less likely to break.

On a sidenote, try to not write every css inline, only those which are really trivial or really important to override without using the notorious "important!" tag